# Does ignite removes caches after expirations?

Tags: c#, .net, ignite

I am using Apache Ignite .NET thin client to create caches for application data. For the caches I set timeout 10 minutes. Recently I've noticed via DBeaver that after expiration caches still exist in Ignite without any data. I've experimented with timeouts in Apache.Ignite.Examples solution (LinqExample.cs) and the behavior is the same: caches are still alive in Ignite and can be viewed by DBeaver and .NET thin client (GetCacheNames method).
I've tried to do the following:

1. Set timeout via ICacheclient.WithExpiryPolicy method
2. Set CacheClientConfiguration.EagerTtl = true
3. Set CacheClientConfiguration.ExpiryPolicyFactory

```
    var cacheNames = ignite.GetCacheNames(); // here I see that expired caches still exist

    var expiryPolicy = new ExpiryPolicy(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        
    var employeeCache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, Employee>(
                        new CacheClientConfiguration(EmployeeCacheName, new QueryEntity(typeof(int), typeof(Employee))) { EagerTtl = true })
                        .WithExpiryPolicy(expiryPolicy);

        var employeeCacheColocated = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<AffinityKey, Employee>(
                    new CacheClientConfiguration(EmployeeCacheNameColocated,
                        new QueryEntity(typeof(AffinityKey), typeof(Employee)))
                    { ExpiryPolicyFactory = new ExpiryPolicyFactory() })
                    .WithExpiryPolicy(expiryPolicy);

        var organizationCache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, Organization>(
                    new CacheClientConfiguration(OrganizationCacheName, new QueryEntity(typeof(int), typeof(Organization))) { EagerTtl = true })
                    .WithExpiryPolicy(expiryPolicy);

        // Populate cache with sample data entries.
        PopulateCache(employeeCache);
        PopulateCache(employeeCacheColocated);
        PopulateCache(organizationCache);
```

...

```
    public class ExpiryPolicyFactory : IFactory<IExpiryPolicy>
    {
        public IExpiryPolicy CreateInstance()
        {
            return new ExpiryPolicy(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        }
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong? How to make expired caches removable in Ignite?

Comment: Expiry policies are only for cache entries. Ignite never removes caches automatically. Can you explain the use case, why do you want to remove the cache as well?

Comment: Pavel, for each screen in application I create a signle cache with records in Ignite and make LINQ requests for sorting, filtering. When the data is expired I expect the cache to be destroyed and application will make request to the database and cache data again. Instead application finds cache without data and displays empty screen without data. Even if I find a workaround and store some expiration flag in the cache it's still unclear why caches are not destroyed. Application can create hundreds of caches depending how many screens users will visit. I thought my use case is rather typical

Comment: This case is not typical at all, did you see it in some other product? Ignite Cache is more like a table in a regular SQL database. Imagine that SQL table gets removed when it gets empty - would be weird, right? @alamar has a good suggestion in a comment below the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Ignite caches are long-lived and their creation/destruction are expensive operations.

Therefore, they are not deleted automatically and I advise against workflows which delete caches often. I recommend reuse.

Comment: in my application I need to cache data temporarily. I mean, after 10 minutes data should be retrived from actual datasource and cached again. How do I differentiate if cache is empty because of expiration or empty data collection is cached? Why cache data removal is not expensive operation towards cache destoy?

Comment: Data removal operation cost depends on amount of data, but it can be parallelized. Cache destruction causes brief cluster-wide locking (the Partition Map Exchange)
So, you are better off keeping separate track of this cache state. Maybe in a different cache.